# Where to put ApplicaitonSettings in a layered mvc project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a basic asp.net MVC project that has a Web project, a Service dll project and a Data dll project. I started to store config values in the web project's applicaiton settings but I've come across a few instances where I need them in the service layer.  The only way I can think of sharing the values is to pass them to the service layer via parameters.  Is there any other way of having one config value that is accessible to all projects?

Comment: Personally I would prefer to pass in these kinds of dependencies as parameters (inject them).  This makes the assemblies re-useable across many projects that may or may not have a config file to pull the required data.  And easier to unit test. Have you tried accessing the web.config from the assembly?  It's my understanding it should already be accessible to referenced assemblies.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey  The service layer doesn't reference the web project.

Comment: Ah, of course.  In that case, I highly recommend you pass them in as params.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to keep config tied to the outermost layer (where it is defined in app.config or web.config) and have that layer explicitly pass through any values which are needed for domain or infrastructure logic, which should be what your lower level layers contain.

I find the notion of having config values contained in the outer layer which are 'magically' used by lower level layers to be rather non-intuitive and opaque.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been answered .. but .. you should never have any dependencies on *.config files in service or data layers. This ads some very tight coupling. The best way is to get them passed in via parameters .. like via constructors.

Even in your website you still shouldn't, IMO. I would use Dependency Injection and inject them into the Controllers, if you really need them. why? Well -> unit testing. Unit tests shouldn't require any *.config file. As such, if your controllers are passed in the data, then your code has no dependencies now -> which is awesome.

[Here's an example of a controller that has no dependencies](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/blob/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web/Controllers/HomeController.cs) on a web.config and [here is how the app setting entries are passed into the controller VIA dependency injection](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/blob/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web/DependencyResolution/AuthenticationRegistry.cs).

Check it out :)

Comment: Thanks, that's how I think I'll end up going!